# Debugging a simple quicksort implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement the quicksort algorithm with Java but it does not properly sort my input array.

My output:

```
1 7 8 9 28 22 45
```

Expected output:

```
1 7 8 9 22 28 45
```

```
public class Quicksort2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {22, 9, 8, 45, 28, 7, 1};
        quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    static void quicksort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        int index = partition(arr, low, high);

        if (low < index - 1) {
            quicksort(arr, low, index - 1);
        }
        if (index > high) {
            quicksort(arr, index, high);
        }
    }

    static int partition(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
        int pivot = arr[(low + high) / 2];
        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivot) i++;
            while (arr[j] > pivot) j--;

            if (i <= j) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me seems that the second condition inside quicksort is wrong:

```
if(index>high) {
   quicksort(arr, index, high);
}
```

should be

```
if (index < high) {
  quicksort(arr, index, high);
}
```

Comment: @ironman [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

An inner while loop for incrementing i / decrementing j isn't respecting the condition `i<=j` set in the parent while loop.

Change the following code:

```
while(arr[i]<pivot) i++;
while(arr[j]>pivot) j--;
```

to this:

```
while(i<=j && arr[i]<pivot) i++;
while(i<=j && arr[j]>pivot) j--;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your top level recursion condition is flawed:

```
if (index > high) {
    quicksort(arr, index, high);
//...
```

This means that the second half of your array never gets sorted. Replace the above two lines with:

```
if (index < high) {
    quicksort(arr, index, high);
//...
```

Or better yet, make your `quicksort()` more compact:

```
static void quicksort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int index = partition(arr, low, high);
        quicksort(arr, low, index - 1);
        quicksort(arr, index, high);
    }
}
```